# How do I add a custom struct to an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I have a custom structure called *pair*, which has two arguments: int winner, and int loser

```
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;
```

I also have an array of pairs called *pairs*, but when I attempt to add a pair to the array, it says,

```
tideman.c:157:37: error: expected expression
                pairs[pair_count] = {i, j};
```

Is there a problem with using curly bracket notation for adding structures to arrays in C? If I make a variable for adding pairs, will it change all the pairs in the array every time I add a new pair (due to mutability problems)?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count] = {i, j};
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`{i, j}` would only work in an initialization (`pair x = {i, j};`). `pairs[pair_count] = {i, j};` would be an assignment, and there you need a variable of type `pair` as the right-hand side. The most straightforward way to obtain one would be to use a compound literal
`pairs[pair_count] = (pair){i, j};`. Alternatively, you can assign to each member separately (`pairs[pair_count].winner=i; pair[pair_count].loser=j;`).